# DropDownList with foreignkey model c#

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, html.dropdownlistfor, argumentnullexception

I have a model with a foreignkey to another models. From this foreignkey, i want to show into my form a DropDownList with the name of my second models. When i go to create.cshtml or edit.cshtml i have the following error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Here's my code:

```
// Models
    public class Timesheet
        {
    public Pharmacy Pharmacy { get; set; }
    }

    // Controllers / ame code on edit.cshtml.cs
    public IActionResult OnGet()
            {
                Dictionary<int, string> pharmacies = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                foreach (Pharmacy p in _context.Pharmacy)
                    pharmacies.Add(p.PharmacyID, p.Name);

                ViewData["PharmacyID"] = pharmacies;
                return Page();
            }
```

Into create/edit.cshtml, the HTML are:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ViewData["PharmacyID"], new SelectList(ViewBag.pharmacies , "key", "value"),"-- select --")
```

I hope you can help me to fix it :)

Thanks per advance !

Comment: ... ,new SelectList(ViewBag.pharmacies), ... maybe this one? You might have mistaken ViewModel and ViewBag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're binding to `ViewData` using lambda expression instead of model property with value type and using unassigned `ViewBag.pharmacies`, hence the binding doesn't work as intended.

You should create a model property first:

```
[BindProperty]
public int PharmacyID { get; set; }
```

And then bound it to `DropDownListFor` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PharmacyID, new SelectList(ViewData["PharmacyID"], "Key", "Value"),"-- select --")
```

Or use `<select>` tag helper:

```
// Page controller (cshtml.cs)
ViewData["PharmacyID"] = new SelectList(pharmacies, "Key", "Value");
```

```html
<!-- CSHTML view -->
<select asp-for="PharmacyID" asp-items="@ViewData["PharmacyID"]" ...></select>
```

Comment: What things doesn't work? Are you found any errors? I think you may try create `PharmacyID` property inside a class inheriting `PageModel`, then use the helper to bind with that property.

Comment: The error are the same of initial: "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null."

Comment: This kind of error usually followed by "parameter name" information, did you checked that? Also try adding viewmodel namespace to `_viewImports` to make sure model binding is enabled.